# Labels not showing on graphic

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In my current script, the label is not showing on the graphic to signal "buy" or "sell" even though I believe to have configured the label correctly.

I already attempted to change the label configurations but still not able to.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Cross Medias Moveis © Teste", overlay=true)

// Definir inputs para os períodos das médias móveis
ma1_length = input(12, title="MA 1 Length")
ma2_length = input(50, title="MA 2 Length")

// Função para calcular a média móvel simples (SMA)
sma(source, length) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to length - 1
        sum := sum + source[i]
    sum / length

// Variáveis para armazenar as médias móveis
ma1 = sma(close, ma1_length)
ma2 = sma(close, ma2_length)

// Adicionar média móvel 1 ao gráfico
plot(ma1, color=color.rgb(54, 255, 114), linewidth=2, title="MA 1")

// Adicionar média móvel 2 ao gráfico
plot(ma2, color=color.rgb(255, 0, 13), linewidth=2, title="MA 2")

// Variáveis para armazenar o estado da estratégia
var bool isLong = na
var bool isShort = na

// Função para verificar a confluência de Sobrevenda e Sobrecompra no RSI
isConfluent(rsi_val, sobrevenda, sobrecompra) =>
    rsi_val < sobrevenda and rsi_val > sobrecompra

// Constantes para níveis de Sobrevenda e Sobrecompra
sobrevenda_level = input(30, title="Sobrevenda")
sobrecompra_level = input(70, title="Sobrecompra")

// Calcular o RSI
rsi_val = ta.rsi(close, 14)

// Lógica da estratégia
if (ma1 > ma2)
    if not isLong and isConfluent(rsi_val, sobrevenda_level, sobrecompra_level)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
        isLong := true
        isShort := false
        // Exibir texto "Long" no gráfico em tamanho grande
        label.new(bar_index, low, text="Long", color=color.green, size=size.large, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_circle)
else if (ma1 < ma2)
    if not isShort and isConfluent(rsi_val, sobrevenda_level, sobrecompra_level)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
        isLong := false
        isShort := true
        // Exibir texto "Short" no gráfico em tamanho grande
        label.new(bar_index, high, text="Short", color=color.red, size=size.large, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_circle)

// Saída da estratégia
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    if isLong and (ma1 < ma2)
        strategy.close("Long")
        isLong
```

I already attempted plenty of ways to change the text or the sign but still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

In your isCongluent function, you test if the number is under sobrevenda AND over sobrecompra.
In your code you test

```
if isConfluent(rsi_val, sobrevenda_level, sobrecompra_level)
```

with

```
sobrevenda_level = 30   
sobrecompra_level = 70
```

So your function will always return false as the number CAN'T be under 30 and over 70.

I think your 'isConfluent' function should be :

```
isConfluent(rsi_val, sobrevenda, sobrecompra) =>
    result = rsi_val > sobrevenda and rsi_val < sobrecompra
```